# Python mplfinance draw hlines start/end date

Tags: python

I have a problem. I am trying to draw hlines in my mplfinance chart. For that I have the following code:

```
levels = [(8531.0, Timestamp('2020-02-27 00:00:00')), (8971.77, Timestamp('2020-02-27 16:00:00')), (8799.0, Timestamp('2020-02-28 22:00:00'))]

mpf.plot(candlesticks,
            type='candle',
            style='charles',
            hlines=levels)
```

I am trying to draw horizontal lines on my chart. These lines are called `hlines` and they need to start at a specific date, so the width of the line shouldn't be the full width of the chart, but if the start date is halfway of the chart. The line should be starting in the middle of the chart through the end. Another thing that is important, is that I want to be able to draw multiple lines, so in my code I had the first line on level `8531.0` starting from `2020-02-27 00:00:00` and another line at level `8971.77` starting from `2020-02-27 16:00:00`, but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Alexander\Projects\MyProject\Python\run.py", line 150, in <module>
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Alexander\Projects\MyProject\Python\run.py", line 128, in run
    graph.plot()
  File "c:\Users\Alexander\Projects\MyProject\Python\graph.py", line 18, in run
    plotCandlestickData(candlesticks[intervalMedium]['candlesticks'])
  File "c:\Users\Alexander\Projects\MyProject\Python\graph.py", line 49, in plotData
    mpf.plot(candlesticks,
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mplfinance\plotting.py", line 389, in plot
    config = _process_kwargs(kwargs, _valid_plot_kwargs())
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mplfinance\_arg_validators.py", line 322, in _process_kwargs
    raise TypeError('kwarg "'+key+'" validator returned False for value: "'+str(value)+'"\n    '+v)
TypeError: kwarg "hlines" validator returned False for value: "[(8531.0, Timestamp('2020-02-27 00:00:00')), (8971.77, Timestamp('2020-02-27 16:00:00')), (8799.0, Timestamp('2020-02-28 22:00:00'))]"
    'Validator'   : lambda value: _hlines_validator(value) },
```

Why am I getting this error? First I thought I should provide another timestamp as endtime, but that resulted in the same error.

When I remove the timestamp from the values, I get a graph like this:
[image]

But those lines you see are all full width, which is not what I want. I want each line to start on a given timestamp. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to vertical and horizontal lines, sloping lines can also be drawn. The settings for such lines can be set in alines in the form of a tuple list. See the [official example](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/using_lines.ipynb).

```
import mplfinance as mpf
import yfinance as yf

candlesticks = yf.download("AAPL", start="2022-01-01", end="2022-04-01")

#levels = [155,160,180]
levels = [[('2022-02-16', 160.), ('2022-03-31',160.0)], [('2022-02-16',175.0),('2022-03-31',175.0)]]

mpf.plot(candlesticks,
         type='candle',
         style='charles',
         alines=dict(alines=levels, colors=['r','b'])
            )
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I get that. But I want each horizontal line to start on a specific date and according to the docs, this is possible, but I dont know why this is not working: https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html

Comment: I am not looking for `alines`.... `hlines` are horizontal, these are not horizontal.....

Comment: I understood that you wanted to draw a closed plug, but since it is a sloping line, the way you specify it changes, so I updated the code and the image.

Comment: No its not a sloping line, I want to draw multiple horizontal lines on the levels I provided in my code. Each horizontal line has to start on the timestamp I provided with the line

Comment: The same method can be used horizontally. Updated code and images

Comment: That doesn't work. All lines are still connected with each other, you just put 3 of the same line values in the dictionary.... If you change the lines to 3 different values, you can see that they start to connect with each other and that they are not horizontal anymore.....

Comment: The way to specify is in list format with a tuple of date (string) and price. If the prices are different, they will not be horizontal. I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by the additional line you are looking for.

Comment: Alright, I will try to explain it more detailed. I am trying to draw horizontal lines on my chart. These lines are `hlines` and they need to start at a specific date, so the width of the line shouldn't be the full width of the chart, but if the startdate is halfway of the chart. The line should be starting in the middle of the chart through the end. Another thing that is important, is that I want to be able to draw multiple lines, so in my code I had the first line on level `8531.0` starting from `2020-02-27 00:00:00` and another line at level `8971.77` starting from `2020-02-27 16:00:00`.

Comment: If you take a look at this link: https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html, you can see that you can provide a `xmin` and `xmax` with a hline, so I think those are the variables for startdate of the line

Comment: I updated this with the understanding that I want to draw two lines to the end, each at a different price. That and the matplotlib functionality is not necessarily available as is.

Comment: `alines` is the correct configuration item, not `hlines`. Please confirm.

Comment: "`alines` is the correct configuration item, not `hlines`"  <-- **This is correct.**  Presently (although it may change some day) in mplfinance, by definition, the `hlines` kwarg draws from one end of the plot to the other.  **Drawing a horizontal line over limited x-values requires use of the `alines` kwarg.**  Sorry for any confusion or inconvenience.